# base64 PDF not displaying in the MAUI Blazor(Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, blazor, maui

I used

```
<embed src="@base64PDF" type='application/pdf'>
```

and

```
<object width="900" height="900" data="@base64PDF" type="application/pdf">
</object>
```

to display a base 64 pdf file.

byte[] bytePdf = System.Convert.FromBase64String(PdfString);

base64PDF = Convert.ToBase64String(bytePdf, 0, bytePdf.Length);

base64PDF = "data:application/pdf;base64," + base64PDF;

base64PDF string pass as the src.

but in these both methods, pdf is showing in windows but not showing in the android. What can be the reason?

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?